# Use of bitcoin address as a security measure

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

One reason for using Bitcoin address is to prevent ourselves from a quantum attacker since he can derive private key from our public key right?
But if we send bitcoin... We anyways require the reciever to have our public key in order to verify the signature... What if the reciever is a quantum attacker? 
What's the point of using addresses then? (Except for relatively smaller size)

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49158/why-do-you-use-bitcoin-addresses-instead-of-public-keys

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming and is much better fit on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Thilo I came here after reading that answer already... That doesn't answer my question.. btw I didn't know that there is another site to ask such questions... So yeah you can go ahead and vote to close the question...(coz dunno why ppl always find a reason to do so XD)

Answer (score 1):

We don't know, how fast first quantum computers will be. Lets imagine, quantum computer (QC) can break secp256k1 public key in a day. In this case, we send bitcoin transaction with signature and public key to the network, and attacker can start breaking public key at this moment. But transaction will be confirmed in 10 minutes (or maybe 60 minutes in the worst case), so even if QC will break public key in a day, attacker cannot steal bitcoins, since transaction is confirmed and there is no way to revert it.

If QC will be able to break public key in a hour or quicker, there will be a problems.

Bitcoin addresses are not completely safe against QC, but they provide some sort of extra security.